# Optimizing Wi-Fi Connectivity

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, optimization

Hello and big thanks to everyone in the askubuntu community who has been more than helpful in the learning process of Linux.

I'm Running ubuntu 12.04.3 on a hp g7 (dual booted with windows 7 utilizing a larger partition of my hard drive for now)

While I'm using the wifi network at the library using windows 7, I can connect with no problems. However when I boot into ubuntu 12.4 I have to move closer to the access point to connect wirelessly.

Chipset info:
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Driver info:
rt2800pci

I also downloaded/installed/updated RutilT  (While learning linux I'm also trying to learn aircrack-ng suite for network auditing purposes)

I will happily provided more info if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot post this as a comment so bear with me. What is the output of

```
iwconfig
```

Check for a field called "Power Management:"

If it is on, then it may be that linux may using less power for your Wifi to save energy. If this works, then you need to make this permanent by editing power configuration settings.

Comment: Well I appreciate you taking the time to help! Your logic is sound. here is the output of iwconfig. wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SalinaPublicLibrary"  
 Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: AC:86:74:09:7E:E2   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:136  Invalid misc:1405   Missed beacon:0

Comment: Everything looks normal. :/ You can try [this](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?4129-Increase-Wi-Fi-TX-Power-Signal-Strength) , or try disabling ipv6. Otherwise, I can't help much. Good luck.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Do I really have to worry about running my wireless card too hot? I don't leave my laptop on 24/7. Thanks again for your help! :-)

Comment: That's up to your judgement. It seems though that your NIC has its share of problems so it may be useful to google the specific card. Here's a [link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=137200) for someone who has dropped packets. I noticed that your " Tx excessive retries:136 Invalid misc:1405" has some dropped packets.

Comment: I'll do more research. Consider me a n00b :-) Linux is fascinating! I don't mind the leg work and wish I would have gave it a shot years ago.